# What are the largest and smallest numbers in decimal base in this special Sudoku?

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, sudoku

I have constructed the following hexadecimal 16×16 sudoku in [this](https://truben.no/table/) site:

[image: Hex]

The rules are like 9×9 sudoku tables (each number and letter should repeat only one time in each column, row, and 4×4 partitions).

What are the largest and smallest numbers in base 10 after completion of the table? Here you can go from top to the bottom or vice-versa in each column, from left to right or vice-versa in each row. That is, reading each row and column in the completed sudoku as a 16-digit hexadecimal number, which row/column would have the highest and lowest value?

Answer (score 0):

The highest value is:

> FC30976D4581B2AE which is the 8th column from the left (from top to bottom) and its decimal equal is $18,172,190,992,013,308,590$

The lowest value is:

> 031F82DACB46795E which is the 7th column from right (and from bottom to the top) and its decimal equal is $225,042,382,616,688,990$.